# Rebalance Akka Cluster if One Of Shard Is not Resolving

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Intermittently we are receiving following errors

```
2022-05-25 08:32:30,691 ERROR app=abc a.c.s.DDataShardCoordinator - The ShardCoordinator was unable to update a distributed state within ‘updating-state-timeout’: 2000 millis (retrying). Perhaps the ShardRegion has not started on all active nodes yet? event=ShardRegionRegistered(Actor[akka://application@10.52.174.4:25520/system/sharding/abcapp#-1665332307])
2022-05-25 08:32:31,348 WARN app=abc a.c.s.ShardRegion - abcapp: Trying to register to coordinator at [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://application@10.52.103.132:25520/), Path(/system/sharding/abcappCoordinator/singleton/coordinator)]], but no acknowledgement. Total [22] buffered messages. [Coordinator [Member(address = akka://application@10.52.103.132:25520, status = Up)] is reachable.]

While we check cluster members by using /cluster/members we got “10.52.174.4:25520” this as

{
“node”: “akka://application@10.52.252.4:25520”,
“nodeUid”: “7353086881718190138”,
“roles”: [
“dc-default”
],
“status”: “Up”
},
```

Which says its healthy but problem resolves while we remove this node from the cluster using

`/cluster/members/{address}` (leave operation to remove 10.52.252.4 from cluster, once it’s removed cluster will create new pod and rebalance.

Need help to understand the best way of handling this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can of course implement an external control plane to parse logs and take a node exhibiting this error out of the cluster.

That said, it's better to understand what's happening here.  The `ShardCoordinator` runs on the oldest node in the cluster, and needs to ensure that there's agreement on things like which nodes own which shards.  It accomplishes this by requiring that updates be acknowledged by a majority of nodes in the cluster.  If a state update isn't acknowledged, then further updates to the state (e.g. rebalances) are delayed.

I said "majority", but because in clusters where there's substantial node turnover relative to the size of the cluster simple majorities can lead to data loss, it becomes more complex.  Consider a cluster of 3 nodes, N1, N2, N3.  N1 (the `ShardCoordinator`) updates state and considers it successful when it and N3 have updated state.  N1 is dropped from the cluster and replaced by N4; N2 becomes the shard coordinator (being the next oldest node) and requests state from itself and the other nodes; N4 responds first.  The result becomes that the state update N1 made is lost.  So two other settings come into play:

- `akka.cluster.coordinator-state.write-majority-plus` (default 3) which adds that to the majority write requirement (rounding down)
- `akka.cluster.distributed-data.majority-min-cap` (default 5) which requires that the majority plus the added nodes must be at least this

If the computed majority is greater than the number of nodes, the majority becomes all nodes.  So in a cluster with fewer than 9 nodes with the defaults these become effectively all nodes (and the actual timeout when updating is a quarter of the configured timeout, to allow for three retries).

You don't say what your cluster size is, but if running in a cluster with fewer than 9 nodes, it can be a good idea to increase the `akka.cluster.sharding.updating-state-timeout` from the default 5 seconds to allow for the increased consistency level.  Decreasing `write-majority-plus` and `majority-min-cap` can be an option, if you're willing to take the risks of violating cluster sharding's guarantees (e.g. multiple instances of the same entity running and potentially destroying their persistent state).  Increasing the cluster size can also be helpful, paradoxically, if the reason other nodes are slow to respond is overload.

Comment: Great stuff, but I'd also add that OP might want to review the stability of the cluster in general. Are there other heartbeat errors? Is there some sort of cgroup throttling or GC that might be delaying responses, is the network low latency? How frequent are changes to the cluster state? Is there something that is causing the oldest node to get bumped?